# magit doesn't recognize repo, can't find git

Tags: git, macos, emacs, magit

Magit doesn't recognize my git repos. I think it can't find my git. When i type

```
M-x magit-version
```

i get

```
Magit 20170322.1550, Git (unknown), Emacs 25.1.1, darwin
```

I am using mac osx. my git is here:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 2.7.1
```

And i can use git commands normally outside of magit. Does anyone know I can get magit to find my git? Adding the path to `.bash_profile` does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I had to install: github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

magit began working for me after this.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `magit-git-executable` tells magit which command to run.  If you set this to `/usr/local/bin/git` it should work.

Alternatively you could add `/usr/local/bin` to `exec-path` and not touch `magit-git-executable`.

Comment: how/where do i set `magit-git-executable` ?

Comment: You can use the customize interface or you can set it yourself in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or `~/.emacs` file.  To use the customize interface run `M-x customize-variable` followed by `magit-git-executable` when prompted for a variable name.

Comment: putting it in `.emacs.d/init.el` worked. But I ran into more problems. https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell solved everything